# Custom key for Home/End on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10

Tags: keyboard, xdotool

My laptop is Thinkpad T440.
Because of Lenovo designing, Home/End key is on header, in the line with F1-F12 keys.
For my convinient, I want to make some custom shortcut key to map with Home/End key. (ex: Alt+PageUp -> Home, Alt+PageDown -> End).

I tried with xdotool, but it was not worked :(

```
   name: Homepress
   command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers Home
   shortcut key: Alt+Page Up
   --
   name: Endpress
   command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers End
   shortcut key: Alt+Page Down
```

What should I do ?

Noted that I don't want to print any special chracters from keyboard with custom shortcut key, I just want to replace "Home/End" key with another key/shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I map a character to a key combination?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2316/how-can-i-map-a-character-to-a-key-combination)

Comment: @sbergeron it is different with my case, I want to define new combination key for "Home/End" key on keyboard, not a character like your article. This like on ubuntu we can use combined key:  Alt+F2 mapped with Super key.

Comment: For your information; it *does* work on my system. Maybe you should check with the command `xev` + Return, then press `Home` and see what is the `keysim` on your system and try to use that instead.

Comment: OP, did you fix your problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with xbindkeys.

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
```

then create a default config:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Add this to .xbindkeysrc:

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers Home"
    Release + Alt + Prior

"xdotool key --clearmodifiers End"
    Release + Alt + Next
```

restart xbindkeys

An alternative is using AutoKey:
[image: AutoKey screenshot]