# How to write a keyboard symbol, e.g. "~", with a key combination, e.g. CTRL+FN+`?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, remapping

My <kbd>1</kbd> key broke and I just used the key-mapper program to move this key to the one on the left (the <kbd>~</kbd> key). Or in other words - I remapped the <kbd>~</kbd> key to take the functionality of <kbd>1</kbd>.

My problem now is that I have no key for writing `~` or `` ` `` which were previously on the <kbd>~</kbd> key.

What I want to do is create a key combination (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or others) that will allow me to type the symbols `` ` `` and `~`.

How is this possible on Ubuntu 20.04?

I looked at the shortcuts menu, but they work only as shortcuts for terminal commands, not for typing symbols (or am I wrong?). I also tried `xkb`, but I think it only remaps one key to one key, not a combination from multiple keys to a key. Do you have other suggestions for me?

Comment: A [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) may be helpful. With that you can type a tilde character for instance like this: **<Compose> space minus**

Comment: @Dan Tnx, This is a smart idea, but the problem is that the program I used for remapping - key-mapper - accepts remapping only on alphanumeric and ordinary symbols like, 2,3,4,a,s,d,],=. But it doesn't accept remapping on "special" keys like Caps Lock (or Right shift, which is also rarely used). Do you know a program, that would allow me this remapping? Tnx

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode entry as a stop gap---e.g. type LEFTSHIFT+LEFTCTL+u, followed by the unicode for tilde, 223c then ENTER. The unicode for backtick (actually an accent grave) is 0060.

I also did a search on AskUbuntu and found this [old answer which is quite comprehensive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2316/how-can-i-map-a-character-to-a-key-combination) One addition I might make is to use `xdotool key asciitilde` instead of the long sequence for the unicode.

Comment: thanks, this is an option that I forgot about! I can use it as an intermediate solution, but it is cumbersome in the long term. Do you know how this sequence of keys can be shortened?